# Python Regex - search and replace matches

Tags: python, regex

```
Vivamus sagittis lacus (name: something) vel augue laoreet 
rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec ullamcorper nulla (name: another_thing) 
metus auctor fringilla.
```

This is my string. There may be multiple patterns like `(name: xxxx)`. I want to find each of them and replace with:  `<a href="something">something</a>`

So, specifically for this example, new string should be like:

```
Vivamus sagittis lacus <a href="something">something</a> vel augue laoreet 
rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. 
Donec ullamcorper nulla <a href="another_thing">another_thing</a>  
metus auctor fringilla.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im most cases, a simple `re.sub` will suffice:

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r'\(name:\s*([^)]+)\)',
                   r'<a href="\1">\1</a>',
                   old_string)
```

However, this assumes that the `name` is syntactically acceptable as an HTML `href` attribute (doesn't contain double quotes, parentheses, &c).  If that hypothesis does not hold, the work can become much more:-)

Comment: is the `<a>` missing the closing tag? more likely `r'<a href="\1">\1</a>'`

Comment: @Anzel right, edited the A to produce the right replacement, thanks.